# Nvim completion menu issue

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol

I'm using lspkind and nvim-cmp with Neovim 0.7.

When `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` is pressed to scroll through the items from the list of possible completions it gets completely overwritten by the standard completion suggestions. See [link](https://asciinema.org/a/tJwTwgBOLEa6SUqwZeUVVIZ3N) for an example.

Why does it change from lspkind suggestions to basic completion?
Why do I get `--keyword completion (^N^P) back to original`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding

```
['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.select_next_item()),
['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.select_prev_item()),
```

inside of the mapping list of the LUA config (I'm not actually sure this is a list I only
use LUA for Nvim)

```
mapping = { ...,
['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.select_next_item()),
['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.select_prev_item()),
...
```

The reason for this issue coming up in the first place is that (from the
config I copied) the select_next_item/select_prev_item functions simply
wasn't bound so there was nothing to overwrite the standard completion.

I found these functions in the cmp [documentation](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp/blob/main/doc/cmp.txt).

Comment: thanks it works like a charm! I think that I've overwrite that mappings during some plugin development!

Comment: Thank you for the solution -- this was driving me crazy! I'm not sure what changed because I did not run into this problem previously.